# Angular 5 Server Side Rendering with TransferState Module doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: angular-universal, angular5

I am using TransferState Module to cached http response on server side but it doesn't seem to work.

What I did was, added **ServerTransferStateModule** to **AppServerModule** and **BrowserTransferStateModule** to **AppModule** as suggested here https://next.angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState

Then I added below interceptor, which intercepts each http request and:

when on server, executes request and stores response in cache.

when on client, check the cache if cached response exists, it returns it otherwise executes request.

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const CACHE_KEY = makeStateKey('httpCacheKey');

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private isServer = isPlatformServer(this.platformId);

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
    private transferState: TransferState,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let modifiedRequest: any;

    let isLocalRequest: boolean = !req.url.startsWith('http');

    if (isLocalRequest) {

      //skip cache check if the request method isn't GET.
      if (req.method == 'GET') {
        // check and serve cached response, if it exists
        const cachedResponse = this.transferState.get(CACHE_KEY, null as any);

        if (cachedResponse) {
          let modifiedResponse = new HttpResponse<any>({ headers: cachedResponse.headers, body: cachedResponse.body, status: cachedResponse.status, statusText: cachedResponse.statusText, url: cachedResponse.url });
          return of(modifiedResponse);
        }
      }

      // Clone the request to add the new header.
      modifiedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers, url: this.baseUrl + req.url, body: req.body });
    }

    return next.handle(isLocalRequest ? modifiedRequest : req)
      .pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          if (this.isServer && isLocalRequest) {
            this.transferState.set(CACHE_KEY, event as any);
          }
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

I do see the response being cached and transferred to client, I see below script tag in the markup returned from server:

```
<script id="ng-cli-universal-state" type="application/json">{&q;httpCacheKey&q;:{&q;headers&q;:{&q;normalizedNames&q;:{},&q;lazyUpdate&q;:null},&q;status&q;:200,&q;statusText&q;:&q;OK&q;,&q;url&q;:&q;http://localhost:49805/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts&q;,&q;ok&q;:true,&q;type&q;:4,&q;body&q;:[{&q;dateFormatted&q;:&q;11/28/2017&q;,&q;temperatureC&q;:28,&q;summary&q;:&q;Mild&q;,&q;temperatureF&q;:82},{&q;dateFormatted&q;:&q;11/29/2017&q;,&q;temperatureC&q;:-15,&q;summary&q;:&q;Balmy&q;,&q;temperatureF&q;:6},{&q;dateFormatted&q;:&q;11/30/2017&q;,&q;temperatureC&q;:51,&q;summary&q;:&q;Freezing&q;,&q;temperatureF&q;:123},{&q;dateFormatted&q;:&q;12/1/2017&q;,&q;temperatureC&q;:45,&q;summary&q;:&q;Mild&q;,&q;temperatureF&q;:112},{&q;dateFormatted&q;:&q;12/2/2017&q;,&q;temperatureC&q;:1,&q;summary&q;:&q;Mild&q;,&q;temperatureF&q;:33}]}}</script>
```

But the http requests are executed twice, once on server and again in browser.

Comment: Just to make sure, you use absolute URLS on the server side, and relative urls on the client side?

Comment: I am using absolute urls on server as well as on client. The state is being transferred from server to client thats why its showing script tag I mentioned above. But when I check cache, its always null.

Comment: I'm not sure how interceptors work (singletons or one new per request?), but you always seem to use the same cache key whatever the requested url is. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Interceptors are new per request, so, that shouldn't be the issue. Even if its singleton it should at least work for first request.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. Found the solution at the end of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c). You need to make sure you are bootstrapping your App Module after the DOMContentLoaded event fires.

`main.ts`:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// Listen for the event before bootstrapping:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin, you are awesome, I was struggling with this since last week :)

Comment: guys i do that in my angular application but it seems the event never happened because i put console.log in function of the event listener and it's never triggered.
have you any idea or suggestion or something could help? :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am experiencing the same but only in production. @s.sobati